# How to get percent from an binary int, with every bit representing x percent?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have an binary bitmap with 10bits. Every bit represents 10%. Is there any simple math function to get the sum of percent from the bitmap?

Sample

```
0000000000 = 0%

0000000001 = 10%
1000000000 = 10%
0000100000 = 10%

1000000001 = 20%
0000000011 = 20%
0000110000 = 20%
0010000010 = 20%

1010000010 = 30%
```

Be aware this is just an example of how the bits are activated. The number i have actually is an int such as 0,1 to 1023.

Comment: So you just want to count the number of bits that are set?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a loop. You don't have to do math. Just do it like this:

```js
var number = 1000100010;
alert(number.toString().split("1").length - 1);

//A little more deep:
var number2 = 1100100000;
alert((number2.toString().split("1").length - 1) * 10 + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
function count_1bits(n, bitsize) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < bitsize; i++) {
        count += (n & 1); // test low-order bit
        n >>= 1; // shift number down 1 bit
    }
    return count;
}

var pct = count_1bits(bitmap, 10)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the bits with a function like this, then just multiply by 10 to get it as percent:

```js
function countBits(n, cnt) {
  if (cnt == 1) return n & 1;
  var half = Math.floor(cnt / 2);
  return countBits(n >> half,  cnt - half) + countBits(n, half);
}

n = 1023;
document.write(countBits(n, 10) * 10 + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
x = '0000100011';

function binTopre(x) {
  c = (x.match(/1/g)||[]).length;
  return (c*10) + '%';
}

 console.log(binTopre(x));//30%
```